# Bootstrap validation with jqBootstrapValidation on hidden radio input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm tring to figure out how to use bootstaps radio inputs like so:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="option5" value="yes" required> yes
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="option6" value="no" required> no
  </label>
</div>
```

and still get the validation message in the right place, because currently the message pops up in the top middle of my page insted of the buttons position. This is caused by the display:none; state of the input radio buttons, but I have no clue how to fix this:

[image]

any ideas how to fix the position?